# iptables rules for drbd

Tags: iptables, drbd

I'm having a default `DROP` policy on the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chain configured for iptables and I am trying to configure proper iptables rules for two servers that mirror data via drbd.

The resource configuration:

```
resource data {
    on data001 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/mapper/vg--system-data;
        meta-disk internal;
        address 10.0.0.10:7788;
    }
    on data002 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/mapper/vg--system-data;
        meta-disk internal;
        address 10.0.0.11:7788;
    }
}
```

For iptables, the following rules are set on both drbd nodes:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 --sport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.11 --sport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.11 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
```

However, drbd cannot properly set up a connection between the hosts. Updating the default policies on both hosts to `ACCEPT` works as expected.

Comment: To debug add a LOG directive to your iptables rules. Also the full output `iptables -n -v -L` would help. And: `-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 --sport 7788 -j ACCEPT` is often wrong, because drbd - as most services - also maps to some random ports. I'd rather create matching OUTPUT rules for related traffic or something. Or e.g. `-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

You should allow `ESTABLISHED` connections for `INPUT` and `OUTPUT`. In addition for the setup of the connection you need to allow packets with destination port 7788, both outgoing and incoming.

**Edit**

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.10 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.0.11 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.10 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.0.0.11 --dport 7788 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Could you give an example on the rules for the sake of completeness?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: This will set a "default ESTABLISHED rule" for all INPUT/OUTPUT connections, not limited to these specific IPs. Sounds nitpicky, but depending on @pduersteler's use-case or expectations this might be too broad.

Comment: @Lenniey My opinion is if you don't want to have connections in `ESTABLISHED` state, you should block them before they get there.

Comment: @RalfFriedl I didn't criticize you, just wanted to clarify it. I'd use your approach too.